# How to port lighttpd for Android(AOSP11/12) in source code

Tags: android, web-services, android-source, lighttpd

I planning to integrate the Lighttpd web server into android(AOPS11/12).

How to integrate Lighttpd in AOSP11/12? and where can we download supported Lighttpd source code fro android

Answer (score 0):

> where can we download supported Lighttpd source code

Official lighttpd site: https://www.lighttpd.net/

Official lighttpd download: https://download.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/

If you find improvements to make building on Android easier, please submit them in the lighttpd support forums
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/boards

e.g. https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/10560

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Generally, how can we integrate Lighttpd in android as like NDK application, do you have any idea? by the way, I have posted questions in the forum. but still not get a reply.

Comment: You definitely got a reply at https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/10571 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73107455/how-to-test-lighttpd-web-server-in-android-device

Comment: I only posted those questions , he is just blaming not giving any clue.Anyway I found solution from my self. Thanks for your message.